# SQL in one set but not in another

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Given the following data:

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE
(
    clientid INT,
    reqyear INT,
    status VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO @Data VALUES
(1, 2017, 'Recd'),
(1, 2018, 'Reject'),
(2, 2017, 'Recd'),
(3, 2017, 'Recd'),
(3, 2018, 'Request'),
(4, 2015, 'Recd'),
(4, 2017, 'Reject');

SELECT * FROM @Data;
```

I need to retrieve a list of client ids where we received documents for one year but were rejected for another year. In this example, I would only want clients 1 and 4.

Client 2 would not be valid because we received in one year but have no data for another year.

Also, client 3 would not be returned because we received in one year but have only requested (and were not rejected) in another year.

How would I write the SQL for this?

Comment: Do you ignore or assert against a rejection the same year?  What if a client has two recd records?

Comment: That doesn't matter. Its only a Recd in one year and Reject in another. Thx

Comment: What have you tried so far?????  `SELECT * FROM @Data` is not trying at all.  Everybody can do that.

Answer (score 3):

You can count the distinct number of `status`es each client has among those two:

```
SELECT   clientid
FROM     @Data
WHERE    status IN ('Recd', 'Reject')
GROUP BY clientid
HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT status) = 2
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1506d/2)**

Comment: @Lamu yup. Stupid typo, thanks for noticing. Edited and fixed.

Comment: La`rn`u, ha! No worries. :)

Comment: @Larnu I'm obviously having a (havinf? :-)) a bad day :-( Sorry about that.

Comment: This returns everything in the table. I'm not sure I understand. Thx

Comment: @CarlGanz this only returns client ids 1 and 4 - see the SQLFiddle I added to the question. Perhaps your example reduced the real problem too much so it no longer represents it?

Answer (score 2):

```
       SELECT distinct d1.clientid  
                FROM @Data d1 
                        join @Data d2 
                                on d1.status = 'Recd' 
                                    AND d2.status = 'Reject' 
                                    and d1.clientid = d2.clientid 
                                    and d1.reqyear != d2.reqyear  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want any client that has a reject but a non-reject on another row?

If so:

```
select clientid
from @data d
group by clientid
having sum(case when status = 'Reject' then 1 else 0 end) not in (count(*), 0);
```

Comment: No, any client who received documents for one year but were rejected for another year

Comment: @CarlGanz . . . That is what this query does.